# HTML PHP Contact Form - Submit and Message Issues

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

Hope you can help, I am trying to knock up a contact form for my website which is HTML, styled with CSS and the email sent with PHP.

Website: [Evan Ciniello](http://www.evanciniello.ca)

Issue One: When a message is submitted through the contact form it does not redirect, or refresh (ends up at www.evanciniello.ca/php/submit.php)

Issue Two: The body of the message itself is not visible in my inbox (i.e I can see who sent the email but can not read the message).

**Contact HTML form**

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
    <div class="element  clearfix col2-3 contact">
            <form id="contact-us" action="/php/submit.php" method="post">
                <h1>Contact Us!</h1>
              <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="NAME" required>
              <input  type="email" name="email" placeholder="MAIL" required>
              <textarea name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE" required ></textarea>
              <input id="button" type="submit" class="submit"></button>
            </form>
             <div id="error" style="display:none;"> Please Provide Valid Information</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**PHP Form**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$to =  "contact@evanciniello.ca";
$subject = "Form Tutorial";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];                
$email_field = $_POST['email'];                             
$message = $_POST['message'];
$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message"; 
$success = mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
?>
```

Comment: For one thing, `$_POST['name']` and `name="first_name"` no match. Edit: Yep, that conditional will surely do it. vvvvvvvvvvvvvv

Comment: There is no redirection in your PHP code. Also, you process conditionally on `$_POST['submit']`, but there is no input named "submit" in your form.

Comment: *"I can see who sent the email but can not read the message"* - Oh? while using that conditional statement you've set for it? Impossible. Nothing's going to work.

Comment: Thanks - Only about four weeks into this. I will be sure to read over my code better before asking...shouldn't need to guys to point out blatant errors.

Appreciate everything, cheers.

Comment: Since you're new to PHP, [**here's an indispensable tool**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) you should be using. Plus, your mail will most likely end up in Spam (or rejected) by not using proper [**mail headers**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. In your `/php/submit.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST["message"]) || empty($_POST["first_name"]) || empty($_POST["email"])) {
        //Set up some error messages here and show that to the users.
    } else {
        $to = "contact@evanciniello.ca";
        $subject = "Form Tutorial";
        $name_field = $_POST['first_name'];
        $email_field = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";
        $success = mail($to, $subject, $body);
        if ($succes) {
            //Now we need to redirect
            $url = "http://www.evanciniello.ca/WHEREYOUWANTTOREDIRECT";
            Header("Location: " . $url);
        } else {
            //Set up error message, that message can not be setn
            die("Message can not be sent");
        }

    }
}
```

Add a `name` to the submit:

```
<input id="button" type="submit" class="submit" name="submit"></button>
```

Comment: You have an error in your answer.

Comment: Cool! Can you point me what error do i have?

Comment: if the name/email, i've just fixed that.

Comment: *Yep*. Now let's see if OP accepts the answer. ;) Edit: *Yep*. `Another happy ending`.

Comment: Thenk you Fred -ii- the edit. I had several errors.

Comment: You're welcome @TaylorCooney - Remember to check for errors and use proper mail headers. Not having a `From:` will not help. *Cheers* - You're welcome also Lolka.

Comment: I still find that I am getting an error message after clicking submit where I end up at evanciniello.ca/php/submit.php

Is that because the redirect is failing?
@lolka_bolka

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: @lolka_bolka Message can not be sent

If you go to the website and try to submit a message you will see.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I believe it is the redirect that is having issues as for the messages are arriving in my inbox

Comment: so you need to check, is your `mail` is configured properly on your host. Maybe you need to use SMTP, not mail function. This error occures, if the mail sending was unsuccessfull.

Comment: @lolka_bolka

the if($succes) 

Needs to be success

Comment: yes. if you will `var_dump($success);` you will get `false`. If the mail is sent to your mail server, then you will get back `true`

Comment: @TaylorCooney As mentioned earlier. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag. For example: 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` - you may even be outputting before header.